# unable to determine row count Ruby-On-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rowcount

im trying to build a cart in ruby on rails it requires me to show the output like this : You have 3 items in your cart (3 being the number of items in my cart) and im trying to find the number of rows in the table line_items where the cart_id is 5.

```
@line_items.find(:all, :condition => { :cart_id => "5"}).count
```

if anyone know how i should write this, please let me know.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it the slow way:

```
YourModelClass.find(:all, :conditions => { :card_id => 5 }).count
```

or the fast way:

```
YourModelClass.count(:conditions => { :card_id => 5 })
```

The fast way simply does a `COUNT(*)` inside the database, the slow way pulls the whole result set out of the database, turns it into objects, and then counts them.

There's also the modern Rails3+ way:

```
YourModelClass.where(:card_id => 5).count
```

That does a `select count(*) from t where card_id = 5` inside the database. **Don't** use this one though:

```
YourModelClass.count(:card_id => 5)
```

That will do a `select count(card_id = 5) from t` and that's nothing at all like what you want.

Comment: Wow the second one is quit an elegant solution, now one last thing if you don't mind, how can i put a variable in the place of 5, what im basically trying to do is {:cart_id => @cart.id } but this doesn't work.. @cart.id is suppose to give me the id of current cart, and its fine it returns 5, yet the whole thing doesn't fit together... ? help :(

Comment: @umer hassam: `{:cart_id => @cart.id }` should be fine if `@cart.id` yields the right value. Are you sure you don't have any stray quotes (i.e. `{:card_id => "@card.id"}`) in there?

Comment: @umar..is it giving an error or 0..If it is 0 it maybe because `@line_items` do not have any record with card_id 5..

Comment: yup it is giving a zero but ive double checked it line_item contains three rows where the cart_id is 5. hay another thing i am writing all this in haml, in the view, you dont think i might have to use #{ } for this.... im currently writing it as:  =link_to(@line_items.count(:conditions => { :cart_id => @cart.id }), :controller => 'carts', :action => 'show')

Comment: @umer hassam: Sorry, I don't know anything about haml. OTOH, `.count` is a class method (i.e. `YourModelClass.count(...)`), not an instance method (i.e. `@line_items.count(...)`) so something like  `@line_items.class.count(:conditions => { :cart_id => @cart.id })` might work.

Answer (score 1):

it should be something alone the line of

```
LineItem.count(:conditions => {:cart_id => 5})
```

since i don't really know what's the model name, and the association... hope this helps =)

Comment: can you plz help me with just one last thing if you don't mind, how can i put a variable in the place of 5, what im basically trying to do is {:cart_id => @cart.id } but this doesn't work.. @cart.id is suppose to give me the id of current cart, and its fine it returns 5, yet the whole thing doesn't fit together... ? help

Comment: u can just do this: @cart.line_items.count =)